# Sabertooth 990FX R3.0 won't enable TPM

Tags: windows-10, motherboard, uefi, tpm

I just installed a brand new `Sabertooth 990FX R3.0` from Asus. I also purchased and successfully installed a TPM chip by ASUS model/part no. `ASUS 90MC03W0-M0XBN1 MK TPM-M R2.0 TPM-chip`. It is a TPM 2.0 compliant chip. 14-1  pins. For the record, ASUS also makes a 20-1 TPM chip which is likely incompatible with Sabertooth.

When I started the UEFI settings for the first time, I was prompted with enabling the TPM support and the TPM itself.

There are actually a few options, most reasonably greyed out when it's the first time.

So I choose to enable

- TPM support
- TPM module

There was a greyed "Pending operation" option which would be likely enabled in the future.

The problem is that:

- Windows 10 never detected the device
- Re-entering UEFI results in TPM support enabled but TPM chip disabled.

Enabling the TPM chip from the settings does not work, no matter how many times I save and reboot.

I found this [very scary topic](https://vip.asus.com/forum/view.aspx?id=20170215034648354&board_id=1&model=SABERTOOTH%20990FX%20R3.0&page=1&SLanguage=en-us) on Asus forums where they discuss an identical situation. No one got a solution yet.

I really hope I don't have to return the mobo and purchase a different model.

Question is: how do I enable TPM and then BitLocker?

Comment: for your information the sabertooth 990fx r2.0 uses the tpm 20.1 module.
I know the latest AM4 boards use the 14.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASUS reported that due to a bug in the chipset's firmware, the TPM function is not available.

It will be fixed in a future release of EFI firmware. This confirms the scary forum post.